# The notions of "monomial" and "induced monomial" in representation theory

Tags: rt.representation-theory, terminology, permutations

Let $G$ be a group and let $\rho : G \rightarrow V$ over a finite-dimensional vector space.

A matrix $M \in \mathbb C^{ k \times k }$ is **monomial** if every row and every of column of that matrix has exactly one non-zero entry. That means that $M$ is the product of a permutation matrix and an invertible diagonal matrix.

We say that $\rho$ is **monomial** if there exists a basis $B = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ of the vector space $V$ such that the linear mappings $\rho(g)$ for $g \in G$ is a monomial matrix. In other words, $G$ is isomorphic to a group of monomial matrices.

We say that $\rho$ is **induced monomial** if it is induced by a one-dimensional representation of $G$.

Many authors write "monomial" for "induced monomial", which is puzzling. Every induced monomial representation is monomial, but some monomial representations are not induced monomial. There are cases where both notions agree, for example, if $\rho$ is irreducible, then $\rho$ is monomial if and only if it is induced monomial (see the textbook by Curtis and Reiner).

What is the justification that "monomial" is used in the sense of "induced monomial"? To me it seems that "monomial" is the property that is actually interesting but that is swept under the rug if use the term in the sense of "induced monomial".

But maybe I am missing some point, and monomial but not induced-monomial representations are not that important for some reason.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson It is not immediately obvious to me that every monomial representation is the direct sum of induced monomial representations. Can you point out a reference for that? For my own purposes, I am actually interested in whether a monomial representation with a monomial direct summand is again monomial.

Comment: I'm not sure about a refeerence, though you might look at some work of Robert Boltje on explicit Brauer induction for one relevant setting, but the argument is quite standard. Note that a representation on the underlying space $V$ is monomial (but not necessarily induced monomial) if and only if $V$ has a basis $\{v_{i}: 1 \leq i \leq n \}$ such that $G$ permutes the $n$ one-dimensional spaces spanned by the respective $v_{i}$. In fact, the representation is induced monomial if and only iif $G$ acts transitively on the $n$ one dimensional subspaces concerned (cont. below)..

Comment: More generally, if $G$ has $t$ orbits on these ome-dimensional subspaces, then this gives a decomposition of $V$ as a direct sum of $t$ $G$-modules, each of which is induced monomial.